# Help understanding/proving : E(n) = O(n) ⋉ $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: proof-writing, cryptography, semidirect-product, orthogonal-matrices

I have been reading through some book, such as Geometry of Crystallographic groups (by Andrzej Szczepanski), and during this reading I came across the relationship: E(n) = O(n) ⋉ $\mathbb{R}^n$. Unfortunately there was no proof attached. I was hoping someone could help me with the proof for this? I'm not really sure how to compare the pairs of elements in O(n) ⋉ $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the Isometries in E(n). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $O(n)$ consists of rotations and reflections about the origin, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists of translations. So for starters, try showing that every element of $E(n)$ is a composite of a rotation or a reflection and a translation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the tip, I have shown the elements of $E(n)$ are of this form. I can see there is clearly a map taking $E(n)$ (given that its elements are in this form) to $O(n)$ ⋉ $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I am still not sure how to show equality?